# Celebrating 10 years of Politics Stack Exchange!

Tags: discussion

Remember, remember the fourth of December when we celebrate our first Politics.SE question: [What are the disadvantages of first-past-the-post electoral systems?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/1)

Ten years, 15,000 questions, and 33,000 answers later, our site has welcomed hundreds of thousands of visitors, and hopefully made at least some difference to broadening political knowledge and furthering our users' understanding of the processes that shape our world. The graph below shows the number of posts created here for each week over the past ten years - with some major political events correlating with traffic peaks highlighted - which I hope goes some way to show that our site is achieving its aim of being a valuable resource during often confusing times.

[image: Graph matching Pol.SE traffic to world events]

As most of you will be aware, [Politics.SE also graduated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/) at the end of 2021, finally cementing our site's place in the Stack Exchange ecosystem. Thank you to everyone who has visited, voted, commented, asked or answered questions, or has otherwise contributed to the site's development.

Over the past decade, monarchs, presidents, and prime ministers have come and gone, but Politics.SE has continued on, in pursuit of our goal of establishing a high-quality knowledge repository, and widening access to the living, breathing world of politics.

## Congratulations & Thank You!

Comment: Interesting that Trump seemed to double post rate for more than his entire term

Comment: Politics.SE also managed to be virtually unaffected by [the internal SE "political" scandal back in 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper). I am happy to be a member of this community and I often reference it as a high-quality source for folks around me who have political questions and want serious answers.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- "double post rate for more than his entire term" My impression is that the whole site took off around 2017 with many question also not being about US politics being posed since then. Maybe it's a side effect. Trump brought more questions which brought more traffic from search engines which attracted also different questions. Overall certainly an achievement. Also thanks to the moderators for all their time spent moderating!